# Lost messages with Spring Reactor

Tags: spring, reactor, project-reactor

I appear to be losing messages sent to a reactor in my Spring application. I suspect that this is due to the time in the lifecycle of the Spring container that I start to produce messages.

In my particular use case there is a Spring Bean which performs some initialisation on startup. Part of this initialisation involves producing a message that is sent to the Reactor.

I suspect that there is an issue with the order that Spring is registering consumers and that the initialisation code has run before the consumers have been registered. If I run the code manually after startup, e.g. make a request to a controller which calls the same code then the messages make it to the consumer.

I tried various ways of changing the time in the lifecycle that the initialisation code runs, e.g. `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>`, `ApplicationListener<ContextStartedEvent>`, `@PostConstruct` method, implementing `InitializingBean` and so on. None of these approaches appear to work.

My consumers are annotated with @reactor.spring.annotation.Consumer and the methods with @reactor.spring.annotation.Selector.Just in case it is relevant, I am using Spring Boot and the auto-configured Reactor (@EnableReactor).

Answer (score 2):

The `ConsumerBeanAutoConfiguration` doesn't run until the `ApplicationContext` is refreshed, which means it won't look for `Consumer` beans until everything's been initialized (including, it sounds like, the beans that emit initial events).

If you put your Reactor configuration on a separate `@Configuration` bean and `@Import` that into your main config, that should make sure the Reactor configuration is complete before your main configuration starts configuring beans and emitting events.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately this doesn't seem to fix the issue either. Just to confirm my understanding; I no longer rely on the Reactor provided by the AutoConfig. I now provide my own, as follows: 
`@Bean public Reactor rootReactor(Environment environment) {return Environment.getRootReactor(); }`  in an `@Configuration` class. I then ensure my Main application class is annotated with: `@EnableReactor
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(ReactorConfiguration.class)`  One more question; where exactly are these messages going if not being delivered to consumers once on the RingBuffer?